# Mysql replication where is ./data?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

By following http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto-rawdata.html

I stuck when it ask me to `shell> tar cf /tmp/db.tar ./data`, where is ./data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is your MySQL data directory. Typical location is `/var/lib/mysql`, but check that out from your `my.cnf` file.

Answer (score 2):

That would be wherever your datafiles are stored. Have a look in your `my.cnf` file for the line

```
datadir = /some/path
```

You will most likely have to modify the command slightly based on what you find. e.g. if your datadir is `/var/lib/mysql` then you would need to

cd /var/lib/mysql
   tar cf /tmp/db.tar ./data

where `data` is the name of the database you want to move.

If you want to move everything then

```
cd /var/lib
tar cf /tmp/db.tar ./mysql
```